# Android VideoView fix height issue

Tags: android, android-videoview

**XML** file

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/video_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

In Activity I have set width and height programmatically

```
 mVideoView.getLayoutParams().height = screenWidth;
 mVideoView.getLayoutParams().width =  screenWidth;
 mVideoView.requestLayout();
```

My issue is when I pick video from gallery which is just captured from default   camera :

**If video is captured in portrait mode** it's being stretched

**If video is captured in landscape** it automatically resize height to landscape video height

Have tried with custom videoview but didn't work any

Any help would be appreciated Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can let the VideoView into a FrameLayout and change the FrameLayout's size.

Maybe [this example](https://github.com/pili-engineering/PLDroidPlayer/blob/master/PLDroidPlayerDemo/app/src/main/java/com/pili/pldroid/playerdemo/VideoViewActivity.java) will help you.

Comment: its too late but Thanks again:) for your ans,  had to dig up deeply in to your example and solved it

Answer (score 0):

If you have trouble with VideoView, you can use this [FullScreen VideoView](https://github.com/rtoshiro/FullscreenVideoView) as they have make the custom class which extending VideoView, and as they have customized and provide the custom class with orientation manage and lots of other features. I am referring to use this as my point of view.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I have already gone through this link but didnt check its customview let me see what change I can make to meet my requirement